# Copy workspace in cloud9

Tags: cloud9-ide

I have a workspace all set up with dependencies etc. installed. I would like to create a copy of this workspace for my coworkers to use so that they don't have to go through the whole process of setting everything up. (What I want is similar to the functionality that vagrant provides, but I want to do it on cloud nine.)

I saw that there was a way to clone workspaces which I thought was doing this, but it seems like that just means cloning from a GitHub etc. repository. I know that I can share the exact workspace so that we both type in the same editor but I don't want that.

Is there a way to do what I want?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Update**

This answer was only valid for c9.io, which has reached end of life. For AWS Cloud9, check out their documentation.

---

There isn't a clone Cloud9 workspace feature yet, but its something that we're working on. For now, the best way to do it would be via Git using the 'Clone from URL' feature that you already discovered.

**Update:**
As of March 2016, Cloud9 supports workspace cloning.

To clone a workspace:

- Go to your dashboard
- Find the workspace you want to clone
- Click Clone
- Set a name for your workspace, choose public / private and you'll have an exact copy of the workspace you cloned.

Comment: This would be amazing!

Comment: Yes, it would be awesome!

Comment: One thing that I would like is to set up a development environment for an open source project along with all the dependencies for testing. I think it will significantly reduce the barrier to new contributors because they will be able to start and hit the ground running; without having to spend a lot of time on set-up of the environment.

Comment: @JosefJezek and others, this should be out in the next couple days. Been testing it internally for quite some time now and this is everything you think it will be.

Comment: @Mutahhir, will we be able to clone public workspaces from other users?

Comment: Is this answer still accurate? I don't seem to have a "Clone" option when I look at my Cloud9 Dashboard. Is it still possible to make a copy of a Cloud9 environment?

Comment: Yeah, this answer is from the c9.io days. AWS Cloud9 is a different thing now. I've added an update to the answer.